# PySide (Qt) signal not reaching my slot

Tags: python, qt, signals, pyside

I have this simplified code that doesn't work and I can't understand why... I expect `MySlot.slt()` to be called every time i press a key in my `QTextEdit` but it doesn't! Could you please have a look?

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

import sys
from PySide import QtGui, QtCore

class MySlot(object):
    def __init__(self, qte):
        qte.textChanged.connect(self.soc)

    def slt(self):
        print("got signal")

class MainWid(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWid, self).__init__(parent)
        self.initgui()

    def initgui(self):
        lay = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        txt = QtGui.QTextEdit(self)
        MySoc(txt)

        lay.addWidget(txt)
        self.setLayout(lay)
        self.show()

def main():
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    wid = MainWid()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__=="__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: A couple of remarks: it is always good to state the actual issue you have - instead of "the code does not work", better explain what you expect and how the code behaves differently. I assume that you do not see the signal delivered to your slot, see my answer below. I also adjusted the tags - it seems that what you called "socket" is really called "slot" in Qt. A [socket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_socket) is something different. +1 for the complete and runnable sample code - this makes it really easy to analyze!

Comment: @Andreas Thank you for the remarks, answer and adjustments ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `MySoc` object in `initgui` has local scope and is therefore destroyed at the end of `initgui`.

Assign the object to a variable:

```
...
self.soc = MySoc(txt);
...
```

and you will see the "got signal" output each time you press a key.